# select2 options have same index id

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select2 select menu working (states from remote geobytes), but I can't select options with the same index id. For example, if I search for "new" I get some options and I can select the first option New Albany, IN. Then, if I type "far", the first option is Far Hills, NJ. When I select it, it shows Albany, IN, which has index 1.

I tried the example for loading remote data, https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax. It does not behave the same way, so I'm wondering if I'm parsing my results wrong. Each time it searches it brings back a new object with indexes starting with 1.

```
$('#input_3_4').select2({
      ajax: {
        url: "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity?callback=?&template=%3Cgeobytes%20city%3E,%20%3Cgeobytes%20code%3E&filter=US",
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: 1500,
        data: function (params) {
          return {
            q: params.term, // search term
            page: params.page
          };
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
          for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
             data[i] = {id:i+1, text:data[i]};
          }
          // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
          // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
          // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
          // scrolling can be used
          params.page = params.page || 1;
          console.log(data);
          return {
            results: data,
            pagination: {
              more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
            }
          };

        },
        cache: true,
      },
      escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
      minimumInputLength: 3,
      //templateResult: formatRepo, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
      //templateSelection: formatRepoSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
   });
```

Comment: I suspect it's because you're reusing the same IDs starting from 1 each time. The example in the documentation uses the IDs that the github API returns, which are unique.

Comment: Is there any way I can avoid that? The data that comes back from geobytes is like this: `?(["New York Mills, MN, United States","New York Mills, NY, United States","New York, NY, United States"]);`

Comment: Use a global variable to keep track of the last ID you assigned, and increment from there each time.

Comment: thanks! I'll try that.

Comment: It worked. I declared a variable `var dataIndex = 1;` outside the select2 function, and then I incremented dataIndex in the for loop in processresults. Is it better to keep track of the last ID I assigned as you instructed? This seems to work fine, and easy, but I'm not that great at javascript.

Comment: Your way is actually the way I was thinking of doing it. Make sure you comment the code to explain it -- it's unusual to use a global variable as a `for` index, but in this case it's the right thing.

Comment: Why don't you post your code as an answer. I don't need the rep, and you can do it more easily by simply pasting your code, to save me the work of writing it up. :)

Comment: certainly. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var dataIndex = 1; //<<=====HERE
    //select2 state selector with geobytes remote data source
    $('#input_3_4').select2({
      ajax: {
        url: "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity?callback=?&template=%3Cgeobytes%20city%3E,%20%3Cgeobytes%20code%3E&filter=US",
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: 1500,
        data: function (params) {
          return {
            q: params.term, // search term
            page: params.page
          };
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
          for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
             data[i] = {id:dataIndex, text:data[i]}; //<<=====HERE
             dataIndex++; //<<=====HERE
          }
          // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
          // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
          // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
          // scrolling can be used
          params.page = params.page || 1;
          console.log(data);
          return {
            results: data,
            pagination: {
              more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
            }
          };

        },
        cache: true,
      },
      escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
      minimumInputLength: 3,
      //templateResult: formatRepo, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
      //templateSelection: formatRepoSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
   });
```